# "String index out of bounds exception" error in random word game's play method

Tags: java, string

I am creating a word game as an assignment for class that randomly generates a 4-letter word using the letters w, x, y, and z and gives the user 10 tries to guess it. The problem is that when I enter 5 letters, I get a string index out of bounds error (StringIndexOutOfBoundsException) instead of printing "The length of the guess did not match the length of the word".

It says the error is in the "lett2 = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(wx));" line. The problem is that my TA helped me write this part of the code, so I assumed all of it was correct. What am I doing wrong?

Method code:

```
   public int play(String str){

      char lett;
      char lett2;
      int total = 0;

      remainingGuesses = remainingGuesses - 1;

      for(int wx = 0; wx < str.length(); wx++) {

      lett = Character.toLowerCase(str.charAt(wx));
      lett2 = Character.toLowerCase(word.charAt(wx));

      if (lett2 == lett) {
         ++total;
         }
      }

      if (total == 4) {
         wordFound = true;
   }

     return total;
   }
```

Main code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GuessingGameMain{

   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      boolean again = true;

      System.out.println("Welcome to Guess Me!");
      System.out.println("A random word will be generated. It will be four letters long and\nconsist of the letters 'W', 'X', 'Y', and 'Z'. Your goal\nis to guess the word within the alloted guesses. Good luck!\n\n");
      GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame();
      //GuessingGame game = new GuessingGame(1234);

      while(again){
         while(!game.isOver()){
            System.out.println("You have " + game.getRemainingGuesses() + " guesses left.");
            System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
            String guess = scan.nextLine();
            int score = game.play(guess);
            System.out.println("There are " + score + " correct letter placements.");
            if(guess.length() != 4) {
               System.out.println("The length of the guess did not match the length of the word.");
            }
         }
         if(game.isWin()){
            System.out.println("Congrats!");
         } else {
            System.out.println("You lose! The word was: " + game.getWord());
         }
         System.out.println("Would you like to play again? y/n");
         if(Character.toLowerCase(scan.nextLine().charAt(0)) == 'n'){
            again = false;
         } else {
            game.reset();
         }
      }
      System.out.println("Goodbye!");
   }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:48)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:709)
    at GuessingGame.play(GuessingGame.java:34)
    at GuessingGameMain.main(GuessingGameMain.java:21)
```

Comment: Where is `word` defined ?  What do you think would happen if `word` is `Cat` and `str` is `Kitten` ? or vice-versa

Comment: please post all code

Comment: `word` is defined in an earlier method, do I need to define it again?

Comment: @beastlyCoder okay

Comment: One quick fix would be to check the lengths first, if there are not equal then it aint going to match

Comment: @ScaryWombat not sure how to do that

Comment: `if (word.length () != str.length () { // fail } `

Comment: *not sure how to do that* - I guess you did not write the original code then

Comment: Nope, it's an assignment for class. I just had to create & declare the instance variables and implement the methods. I also did not write any of the GuessingGameMain class, it was all given to us.

Comment: Please also paste your error stacktrace / Logcat outpur

Comment: are you saying when you send seed greater than four to the constructor the error comes , i din't quite understand you question , where do you enter a string greater than 4 can you highlight the line , and where the actual error is can you also highlight me that line

Comment: @TheGoldy it says the line of the error in the error message. I also have resolved this problem so don't worry about it! (You enter a string greater than 4 when you run the program and play the game.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this "if" statement to the start of your "play" method. It will handle the "too large" case for you.

```
if(str.length() > 4)
{
  System.out.println("Warning! Too many characters detected. Only reading top 4");
  str = str.substring(0,3);
}
```

Comment: I would except my prof told us we did not have to edit that and should only have to edit the other class.

Comment: In that case, all you'd have to do is modify the "play" method of the game class to do a preliminary check if the input string is length 4. If it's not, do a print and return false, otherwise continue execution. If that fits your needs, I can modify my answer's code to fit that need.

Comment: It prints the statement but still gives me an error.

Comment: actually, not sure I modified it correctly. Could you please modify your code?

Comment: If the modification is giving you trouble, I gave you a streamlined answer. Just add that code to the start of your "play method" and it ought to work. The fact that you can't edit that first snippet sucks though. I would give your professor flack for forcing students to violate the DRY principal.

Comment: No worries! Good luck on your coding journey!